# In Angular ： i can't get the value from $scope's properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a button on the page, I expected control it show or hide by different properties value:

```
<a href="" role="button" class="btn-unworking" ng-show="d.status === '0'" ng-click="cancel(d.from)">cancel</a>

<a href="" role="button" class="btn-working" ng-show="d.status === '1'"></a>

<a href="" role="button" class="btn-done" ng-show="d.status === '-1'"></a>
```

This is my data obj:

```
$scope.designedTimeList.push({
            from: $scope.fromTime,
            duration: $scope.durationTime,
            theme: $scope.theme,
            plan: $scope.plan,
            status: '0'
        });
```

Right now, I want to match the time between `fromTime` and realtime:

```
var date = new Date();

        var hour = date.getHours();
        var minute = date.getMinutes();

        var existHour = +($scope.designedTimeList[0].from.subString(0, 2));
        var existMinute = $scope.designedTimeList[0].duration;
        // i just wanna get the first element in the `designedTimeList`

        if (existHour == hour && existMinute >= minute) {
            $scope.designedTimeList[0].status = '1';
        } else if (existHour < hour || (existHour == hour && existMinute < minute)) {
            $scope.designedTimeList[0].status = '-1';

        }
```

But when I use this:

```
$scope.designedTimeList[0].from.subString(0, 2);
$scope.designedTimeList[0].duration;
```

it log `TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined`,`TypeError: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined`

the data in the $scope.designedTimeList is like this:

```
[{duration: "15 min",from: "2 am",plan: "test",status: "0",theme: "test"},{},{}...]
```

Please tell me what's the problem and how to figure it out.

cancel code :

```
    var checkTime = function() {

        var date = new Date();

        var hour = date.getHours();
        var minute = date.getMinutes();

        // var temp = $scope.



            var existHour = +($scope.designedTimeList[0].from.subString(0, 2));
            var existMinute = $scope.designedTimeList[0].duration;

            if (existHour == hour && existMinute >= minute) {
                $scope.designedTimeList[0].status = '1';
            } else if (existHour < hour || (existHour == hour && existMinute < minute)) {
                $scope.designedTimeList[0].status = '-1';

            }

            console.log($scope.designedTimeList[0]);

            $timeout(checkTime, 1000 * 60 * 1);


    }

            $timeout(checkTime,0);
```

Comment: If you debug it and go on that line `$scope.designedTimeList[0].from.subString(0, 2);` what does the console says when you write `$scope.designedTimeList[0]`?

Comment: a.... it is undefined! , actually in this project , i need match the time every minute , i use $timeout to call itself every minute , so at the first time there is no data , so it was occurred error !?

Comment: Show us controller code including cancel method.

Comment: What @Marin Takanov is getting at is that you're not accessing the object within your array properly. Throw this code into the console and you should be able to see the object structure that will allow you to grab that data.

Comment: i don't know the way i write is good or bad , please give me some advice please ~ , i want to make code better ~

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing in an array you have to tell that $scope.designedTimeList is an array.
so you have to write

```
$scope.designedTimeList = [];
```

and after that

```
$scope.designedTimeList.push({
        from: $scope.fromTime,
        duration: $scope.durationTime,
        theme: $scope.theme,
        plan: $scope.plan,
        status: '0'
    });
```

another thing, you have to write susbstring not "subString" 
i.e

```
$scope.designedTimeList[0].from.substring(0, 2);
```